# Compare lists in the same dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In resume, I have two keys in the same dictionary where each one has their corresponding lists.

I try to compare both list to check common and differential elements. It means that the output I will count how many elements are identical or present in only one key's list.

from the beginning I am inserting the elements using the files as arguments and they are read in the function

```
def shared(list):
        dict_shared = {}
        for i in list:
                infile = open(i, 'r')
                if i not in dict_shared:
                        dict_shared[i] = []

                for line in infile:
                        dict_shared[spacer].append(record.id)

        return dict_shared
```

Now I am stuck trying to find a way to compare the lists created and present in the dictionary.

```
dict = {a:[1,2,3,4,5], b:[2,3,4,6]}
```

My intention is to compare the lists in order to have the lines shared between two texts.

```
a: [1,5]
b: [6]
a-b: [2,3,4]
```

From now I can't find a way to solve this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why `a` == [2,5]?Not [1,5]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with files, but you should pretty much always use ```open``` in a ```with open(...) as file:``` block, so that it automatically closes/releases the file when it is no longer necessary.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, thank you for remarking that

Comment: @JohannesAck it will not be a big problem but I will accept your suggestion.

Comment: This also could be done with numpy (for performance issues) Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613249/numpy-comparing-elements-in-two-arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with list comprehension would be:

```
dictionary = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[2,3,4,6]}

only_in_a = [x for x in dictionary['a'] if not x in dictionary['b']]
only_in_b = [x for x in dictionary['b'] if not x in dictionary['a']]
in_both = [x for x in dictionary['a'] if x in dictionary['b']]
```

Note that this is not especially wise in terms of complexity, for larger lists.

Comment: That's my case. Some files contains more than 3000 lines.

Answer (score 5):

You could use set:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[2,3,4,6]}
print(list(set(d['a'])-set(d['b'])))
print(list(set(d['b'])-set(d['a'])))
print(list(set(d['b'])&set(d['a'])))
```

result:

```
[1, 5]
[6]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to do it writing less lines in the code

Comment: Hmmmm,I think three lines is not very much.Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

you can do that by utilising `python` inbuilt functions like `union`, `difference`, `intersection`.
 **Note:** These are for `sets`, 
 you can convert a `list` to `set` by

`1stset = set(a)`

example:

```
print(1stset.difference(2ndset))

print(1stset.intersection(2ndset))

print(1stset.union(2ndset))
```

you can refer the following links for more information

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-union-two-lists/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-two-lists/

Comment: it is consider better to provide solution or stackoverflow link than other website link for other benefits

Comment: I saw it before to come here but in my case I have the lists in one dictionary, so I was trying to do it in some recursive way.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve but it seems like you'd need set operations:

```
dictionary = {"a":[1,2,3,4,5], "b":[2,3,4,6]}

#in a but not in b
set(dictionary["a"]) - set(dictionary["b"])

#in b but not in a
set(dictionary["b"]) - set(dictionary["a"])

#union of both
set(dictionary["b"]).union(set(dictionary["a"]))

#intersection of both
set(dictionary["b"]).intersection(set(dictionary["a"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
mydict = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,6]}

>>> list(set(mydict['a']).intersection(mydict['b']))  # common to both
 [2, 3, 4]
>>> list(set(mydict['a']).difference(mydict['b']))  # a - b
 [1, 5]
>>> list(set(mydict['b']).difference(mydict['a']))  # b - a
 [6]
>>> list(set(mydict['a']).union(mydict['b']))  # union of both
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
print("a - b : {} ".format(list(set(_dict['a']) - set(_dict['b']))))
print('b - a : {} '.format(list(set(_dict['b']) - set(_dict['a']))))
print('a \u2229 b : {} '.format(list(set(_dict['a']).intersection(set(_dict['b'])))))
```

**Output**

```
a - b : [1, 5] 
b - a : [6] 
a ∩ b : [2, 3, 4]
```